# Parsing amazon product pages is returning gibberish

Tags: character-encoding, amazon-product-api

I have been using java to parse some amazon product pages, and this was working fine till a few days back. However, recently I have started noticing that Amazon is returning gibberish instead.

Example (using curl) :
curl https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00TYK2AZK/

Can anyone help me out with some pointers on this? Has Amazon recently started using any new encoding?

Cheers,
Rohitesh

Comment: Try 'curl -L https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00TYK2AZK/  | gunzip'

Comment: Using gunzip worked! Silly of me, not to have tried it. I am using java, so I added it in the request header. And it is working. If you post this as an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I used java's URLConnection and it's fine in about 4 out of 5 requests. Valid HTML. Every other time it returns giberrish cause of 503 error code and error stream is used. have you checked HTTP response code?

Comment: It was an issue of compression. The response was compressed. I added decompression header and it started working.